# What concert/opera/ballet is playing? the difference between "который / какой"

Tags: перевод, грамматика

If I want to ask what concert/opera/ballet is playing would:
"Который спектакль идёт?" be correct or is there a better phrase that is used more commonly?

Comment: For *"Который спектакль идёт?"* the answer should be "the second, the third, a previous,  a matinee, and so on... ". For *"Какой спектакль идёт?"*  you answer with the title of a show: "the Mappet's show"

Answer (score 2):

*Который* is wrong in this case. You may only say *Какой*.

Also talking about "classical shows", like classical music concert, opera or ballet, there's a tradition to use the verb "*давать*" instead of "*идти*".

E.g. *What ballet is playing in Bolshoi* = *Какой балет дают в Большом*? Although nowadays many people say "идёт" too.

Comment: Would "classical shows" include a movie/film like "Doktor Zivago"?

Comment: @Ana No, movies do not count. "Какой фильм идёт" or "Какое кино идёт" - the latter is a bit incorrect but is quite colloquial.

Comment: Положим, я звоню товарищу на мобильный. Он отвечает, что прямо сейчас на спектакле. Я как должен его спросить: *"А какой спектакль идет?"* или *"А какой спектакль дают?"*

Comment: Colloquially one would rather ask "Что идёт?" or "Что дают?". "Какой балет" seems unnecessarily cumbersome.

Comment: @Avtokod Ну вообще-то разговаривать во время спектакля по мобильному нехорошо, так что нужно просто отбиться )) А так, можно использовать тот глагол, который Вы обычно употребляете в таких случаях. То есть, "А какой спектакль дают?" вполне нормально и в данном контексте.

Comment: @AndreyChernyakhovskiy Yes, if there's no ambiguity, one may shorten the sentence. But, say, you want to know what _ballet_ (and not opera) is playing in Bolshoi, you can't shorten this.

Comment: Может, неделю назад встречаю режиссера, и вот такой диалог у нас состоялся: *"Привет, Наташа! Давненько не видел тебя!" — Я была в (называет страну). "А что там делала?" — Мы дали два концерта, и …, и ….* Чувствуете разницу? )) Они "дали" два концерта, а не они "шли" два концерта. Они -> дают, а концерты -> идут. Поэтому, если речь о труппе или о театре, то это "они", и они дают. А если речь о спектакле/кино/премьере/…, то он(о) идет. Не вижу оснований относить к категориям "высокий стиль/разговорный"  фразу "дают спектакль".

Comment: @Avtokod Ну собственно традиция заключается в том, чтобы _не использовать_ сочетание "спектакль/опера идёт" даже там, где это в принципе возможно. Понятно, что "дают" в любом случае относится к труппе/оркестру и т.п. (Потому никак нельзя, например, "дать фильм").